# How can I share a picture from my application to Whatsapp?

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

I`ve searched a few solutions here but only for **iOS**. How can I share a picture from my **Android** application to Whatsapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet of code.

```
public void shareImageWhatsApp() {

    Bitmap adv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.adv);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    adv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"temporary_file.jpg"));
    if(isPackageInstalled("com.whatsapp",this)){
          share.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Install Whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are cluttering up the root of the user's external storage with `temporary_file.jpg`. Either put the file in `getExternalFilesDir()` or, better yet, serve the file from internal storage via `FileProvider`. Also, you are hard-coding a package name, which will not support other WhatsApp clients, including any other ones that Facebook/WhatsApp elect to publish in the future.

Comment: if this hardcode package name how change to work with other clients?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here it's pretty straight forward.
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html